# Printing out results of Json API Request on Java/Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, get

I am using the following guide demonstrated by Konstantin Burov on a Stackoverflow post ([Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android/3506039#3506039)):

First of all, request a permission to access network, add following to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then the easiest way is to use Apache http client bundled with Android:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        String responseString = out.toString();
        //..more logic
    } else{
        //Closes the connection.
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
```

If you want it to run on separate thread I'd recommend extending AsyncTask:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

You then can make a request by:

```
   new RequestTask().execute("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

---

My question is how do I now post the actual results in a string? All i'm getting is the address when I do new RequestTask().execute(url).toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is delivered as an argument to `onPostExecute(String)`.
You're supposed to handle the response in this method. Be aware that `onPostExecute(String)` is run on the UI thread, so you cannot do lengthy operations as part of this method.

When you call `new RequestTask().execute(url).toString();` you're simply invoking the `toString()` method of your `AsyncTask` ([check the return value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) of `execute()`: it simply returns `this`, i.e. the AsyncTask that you're calling `execute()` on).